# Inconsistent Xbee LED blinking while controlling remotely

Tags: python, led, xbee, blink

I am trying to blink an LED using a router AT XBee which is controlled by a coordinator API Xbee. The coordinator Xbee is connected to a Raspberry Pi which runs the following program. The LED blinks consistently for exactly 4 cycles but after that, it blinks inconsistently (gets stuck and doesnt light and then blinks super fast, again gets stuck). Sometimes, even after the program is stopped, the LED blinks after few seconds. What is causing the delay and inconsistency, I failed to figure out. I'd appreciate any pointers. Thanks.
Baud Rate: 9600

```
from xbee import XBee, ZigBee
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', 9600)
xbee = ZigBee(ser)

while True:
    try:
        xbee.send('remote_at',
              frame_id='A',
              dest_addr_long='\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xFF',
              dest_addr='\xFF\xFE',
              options='\x02',
              command='P2',
              parameter='\x05')

        time.sleep(1)

        xbee.send('remote_at',
              frame_id='A',
              dest_addr_long='\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xFF',
              dest_addr='\xFF\xFE',
              options='\x02',
              command='P2',
              parameter='\x04')

        time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

xbee.send('remote_at',
      frame_id='A',
      dest_addr_long='\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xFF\xFF',
      dest_addr='\xFF\xFE',
      options='\x02',
      command='P2',
      parameter='\x04')

ser.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, try switching from broadcast to unicast packets by setting `dest_addr_long` (and not setting `dest_addr` at all).  My recollection is that broadcast packets are sent a total of three times to ensure they're received on the remote device.  There probably isn't much traffic on your network, but I think you'll see more reliable timing with unicast.

Second, try switching to 115200 bps.  It will streamline communication between the Raspberry Pi and coordinator, and eliminate possible serial buffering delays.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not solve the problem. After digging more into the data manual (https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Zigbee/XBee-Manual.pdf), this is what I found: P10: 
"If the DI buffer becomes full, hardware or software flow control must be implemented in order to prevent overflow (loss of data between the host and module)."
P11: "When RF data is received, the data enters the DO buffer and is sent out the serial port to a host device. Once the DO Buffer reaches capacity, any additional incoming RF data is lost". Is there a way to know which buffer (DI or DO) is getting full?

Comment: I doubt this is buffer overflow.  You're sending small packets once per second.